# ¿Cómo solucionar un System.NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estoy trabajando en c#, con wpf y sql server.
El programa compila correctamente, pero me da un error de excepción.

al darle click sobre el boton registrar, me sale[image: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instanciia de un objeto]

Pero si en el programa comento esta linea de 
codigo no me aparece el error

```
Cls_UsuarioADO usuarioADO;
usuarioADO= new Cls_UsuarioADO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexion"]
                                .ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Depura tu aplicación para ver que está sucediendo, pero lo mas probable es que `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexion"].ConnectionString` no esté encontrando nada

Comment: Debes encerrar tu código en un bloque `try/catch` y captura la descripción completa del error: así: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace); }`. Ese error que tienes puede deberse a que no existe una conexión llamada `strConexion`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 try
    {
    Cls_UsuarioADO usuarioADO;
    usuarioADO= new Cls_UsuarioADO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexion"]
                                    .ConnectionString);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    ...
    }
```

Revisa los connectionstrings de app.config.

Comment: Usar [Pokémon Exception Handling](http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling) no soluciona nada, solo ignora la excepción.

Comment: Como bien he escrito ,tiene que revisar las connectionstring del app.config/web.config . Yaq que si la conectionstring no existe en esa config, el ConfigurationManager da excepcion.